# dependency issue in android 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

```
 dependencies {

 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-rc01'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'been 
}
```

I have error  with regards to dependency in `Android studio 3.1.3` for `appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01` and even for rc02 similarly for com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2 and 1.1.3 layout. how can I solve it?

[dependency issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYkNZ.png)

[build description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dmx8.png)
[app file for build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPhJi.png)

Comment: can you please add the screenshot of your error?

Comment: post full Gradle.

Comment: post your error

Comment: Have you changed compile SDK version to 28? Please post your error log. In future, always post your errors in your question, that will help fix your issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lower version of appcompat like this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Also remember to change sdkVersion to 27

Comment: I have done that still I get error ,even I have changed sdpcompile version and target version to 27 still I get error

Answer (score 0):

I have these Dependencies so you can use any if you want and make sure to turn off the Offline Work in the Settings->Gradle to get it working.

I was searching for these errors when i came through that by disabling the Offline Work in Settings->Gradle you can get it sync without any errors.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
// google play services
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Regards